# Interdependent headers not compiling

Tags: c

I have 2 headers that depend on each other, both are guarded. But compilation fails as if the type weren't declared:

```
error: unknown type name Type_1
```

the first header:

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

#include "header2.h"

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
} Type_1;

void function(Type_3 *type_3);

#endif
```

second header

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

#include "header1.h"

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_1 *c;
} Type_2;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_2 *c;
} Type_3;


#endif
```

How to solve it without resorting to hacks?

Comment: you ran into a circular dependency I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must forward declare at least one struct.  I'd personally put them all in one header, since there's not that much there.

First header:

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

#include "header2.h"

typedef struct Type_1 {
    int a;
    char *b;
} Type_1;

void function(Type_3 *type_3);

#endif
```

The second header:

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

struct Type_1;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    struct Type_1 *c;
} Type_2;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_2 *c;
} Type_3;


#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all your types definitions to one files and functions declarations to another one.

header1.h

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H
typedef struct {
  int a;
   char *b;
} Type_1;


typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_1 *c;
} Type_2;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_2 *c;
} Type_3;

#endif
```

header2.h

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H
#include "header1.h"


void function(Type_3 *type_3);

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use your structures as imcomplete data types, forward declaration is enough:

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

struct Type1;
typedef struct Type1 Type1;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_1 *c;
} Type_2;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    Type_2 *c;
} Type_3;


#endif
```

Apply same technique to second file. Though, in source code, you need to include header if you don't use your structures as incomplete types. More information about incomplete data types is available in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/200xfxh6.aspx)